# android connect wifi after x minutes and disconnect after x minutes. now repeat again

Tags: android

In `Service` I want to register `BroadcastReceiver` for `android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED`

```
public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        final IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED");      

        MyReceiver myreceiver = new MyReceiver();

        // Register the receiver so that your service will listen for broadcast
        registerReceiver(myreceiver , filter);
```

everything is good and works but after wifi state has changed for example is disconnected I want that is activated again in 5 minutes for 1 minute and then disconnected again. And after 5 minutes activated again for 1 minute. Generally connect after 5 minutes for just 1 minute and disconnect again...

I try this with `AlarmManager` but I am having problems how to achive that is connected after 5 minutes for 1 minute and then disconnect.

My code which is not what i try to do. It is not connected and then disconnected :

```
AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(this, WifiReceiver.class);
            PendingIntent pendingAlarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, alarmIntent, 0);

            // start in 5 minutes and rest in 1 minutes interval
            alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, 5*60*1000, 1*60*1000,  pendingAlarmIntent);
```

How can i do this? I AlarmManager correct way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use some timers to do it in your service...

```
boolean delayedAgain = false;
long newDelayedTimeFromNow;
private Handler mHandlerTime = new Handler();
////////////////////// 
Runnable  mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() {             
    public void run() {
        if(delayedAgain)
        {

        }
        else
        {

    }
}; 
///to start timer 
      mHandlerTime.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
      mHandlerTime.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask, gps_interval);
```

SO you can determine one timer for 5 min to switch WIFI on and other for 6 min to switch off... Play with **boolean dealyedAgain** to make it... f.e. when first is out off 5 min change bool to true, and second will go when run ti **if(..== true)**